# redirect a domain if it isnt a certain file type

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm in the process of setting up a static cookieless domain, and everything is working great!

But im wanting to know how to redirect if the request isn't to an image/js/css file, to avoid duplicate content from the cookieless domain.

I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://files\.my-static-site\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(html|php)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

and it works, but it still loads the home page if you simply put files.my-static-site.com.

If you click on a link on the page your shown a 403. How do i change that to 301 redirect to the main domain instead of showing a 403?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^files\.my-static-site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(html|php)$ http://main.domain.com/ [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^files\.my-static-site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://main.domain.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
```